# Difference between Unicast listener and multicast listener

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

Im working on setting up a coherence cache cluster, while configuring the Cluster i came across config `<unicast-listener>` and `<multicast-listener>`. Im using replicated cache with 2 nodes. What these two configs differ and what criteria to be considered to choose one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It configures how cluster nodes discover and communicate with each other. unicast-listener uses normal point-to-point communication, while multicast-listener uses IP protocol's multicasting feature to communicate among nodes. multicast-listener discovers other nodes automatically, while unicast-listener uses well-known-addresses (config setting) to describe what nodes make up a cluster.